# does yum keep cache of not successfull update

Tags: linux, fedora, yum

I would like to know does yum keep cash of downloaded packages if update was not successful, for example during update computer was restarted, but some packages were downloaded.
Will it redownload already downloaded packages or will continue downloading others ? 
Actually keepcache option in config file says that it keeps downloaded files if installation was successful ... but what about it it is not successful ?

Answer (score 0):

If you quit during the download, or the network dies, etc. Then yum will happily keep what has already been downloaded and continue when you next ask it to.

Note that though if you are updating to foo-2, and download half of it, but then the next time you use yum foo-3 is available then yum will just leave foo-2 alone and try to update to foo-3 (and thus. download it).